# Google ReCAPTCHA in ASP .NET application No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: asp.net-core, recaptcha, firewall, recaptcha-v3

I am unable to verify the Google reCAPTCHA v3 due to an error which is occurring when I try to verify the Token.
The only thing is that, I am able to make this work in my personal machine, But in the production environment, where there is firewall and restrictions, this is not working.
And the error given is as below:

**No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (`www.google.com:443`)**

I have whitelisted in the firewall, the page `www.google.com` and the URLs like:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js
```

And in the reCAPTCHA portal,
If I am accessing the website from a URL with `https://localhost/`, I need to mention only that in the Domains list in the reCAPTCHA portal as "localhost". Right?
As a result I am getting the challenge the tick mark, and the token in backend as well.
The issue is with verification part only.

Below is the code I am using for verification:

```
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
            "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
            new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "secret", secretKey }, { "response", recaptchaToken }
            }));
    
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var recaptchaResponse =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecaptchaResponse>(responseContent);
            return recaptchaResponse.Success;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is this because a network restriction in the server or from the target google machine as in the response content.
Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: could you try to ping the google from your machine. add the outbound connections to `www.google.com` on port 443 in the firewall settings of your production environment.